# Quarkus Native Image Build Failure

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm

I am attempting to build a native image on MacOS for an AWS Lambda function. The application compiles and runs just fine in the IDE, but I am hitting the following issue(s) when I try the native image build:

```
 mvn clean install -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
 mvn clean install -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

1. With following in my pom.xml file, the build fails

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
       <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

> Error: Unsupported features in 4 methods Detailed message: Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image
> heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed
> values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got
> instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.Random. The
> object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable
> from a static field. You can request class initialization at image
> runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=. Or
> you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly
> from your main entry point. Trace: Object was reached by
> reading field com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$EqualJitterBackoffStrategy.random
> of
> constant com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$EqualJitterBackoffStrategy@a7c6c06
> reached by
> reading field com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$SDKDefaultBackoffStrategy.equalJitterBackoffStrategy
> of
> constant com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedBackoffStrategies$SDKDefaultBackoffStrategy@6f61d2d9
> reached by
> scanning method com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedRetryPolicies.getDefaultBackoffStrategy(PredefinedRetryPolicies.java:110)

- If I change the pom file to the following

  ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
       <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda-archetype</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.2.Final</version>
   </dependency>
  ```

the build succeeds without error, but the function.zip for example is not created in the /target directory.

[Content of the /target directory]

- com_abc_demo_xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar
- com_abc_demo_xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
- com_abc_demo_xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- failsafe-reports
- generated-sources
- maven-archiver
- maven-status
- quarkus-app
- quarkus-artifact.properties

[Test Environment]

- Java Version 11.0.6
- Docker Desktop 4.1.1
- macOS Monterey
- Maven 3.8.3
- GraalVM: graalvm-ce-java11-21.3.0
- JAVA_PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
- GRAALVM_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.3.0/Contents/Home

Even with the debug feature enabled it does not make sense to me how to resolve this matter.

Les

Answer (score 6):

[By default, Quarkus initializes all classes at build time.](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#delaying-class-initialization)

This means that if you use Random/SplittableRandom in your code this will be initialized at build time and thus this error.

As mentioned above, this problem occurs when you try to initialize these classes in a static block like for instance:

```java
public class RandomWrapper {

    public static final Random random;

    static {
        random = new Random();
    }
}
```

which fails with your error. However, as the exception tells you, you can specify which classes should be initialized at runtime with `--initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>` flag. In Quarkus, this can be done by specifying the following configuration in your `application.properties`:

```xml
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=--initialize-at-run-time=org.acme.RandomWrapper
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin. I have not used Random/SplittableRandom but possible the libraries from AWS do so. I managed to narrow down the cause of the error to the following two depencies - aws-java-sdk-s3 & aws-java-sdk.

Comment: Your problem is in [aws-java-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/retry/PredefinedRetryPolicies.java) which I found from the classes in your stacktrace in the original question. I would suggest adding these to initialize-at-run-time build args. I'm sorry but I can't reproduce this problem on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make this part of the build. I personally prefer yaml properties, so the first thing to add to the pom is the ability to use yaml properties:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

then in your `application.yaml` in the `src/main/resources` add the commandline options you need, e.g.

```yaml
quarkus:
  banner:
    enabled: false

  native:
    additional-build-args:
      - --initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4JLogger,io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4JLogger
      - --allow-incomplete-classpath
```

As for the S3 issue with the Random, you could look to the [quarkiverse](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-amazon-services), on [Maven Central Quarkiverse](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkiverse.amazonservices)
and their s3 module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.amazonservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```